# Which version of SWT should I run on 64bit OS with a 32bit JVM?

Tags: operating-system, jvm, swt, eclipse-rcp

I am running a **64bit of Windows** 7. 
I am executing an Eclipse RCP application on a **32bit JVM**.

Which version of SWT should I use? 32 or 64 bit?

Comment: If you are using an Eclipse RCP the SWT code is included in the RCP, the whole RCP must be 32 bit

Comment: What does it depend on, which version of swt to use is my question. On the JVM or on the platform? There is no "whole RCP", swt may be extracted to a bundle and then its up to you which version to include into your dependencies

Comment: As I said everything in an RCP must be 32 bit or 64 bit, you can't mix them. Which you use depends only on the JVM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 32 bit. The launcher (.exe) will seek for a 32bit version of Java Installed, which your JVM is.